# C# - Protect the App to no abort

Tags: c#

My App receives a string from serial port in the format "・99,99999,99999,99999,AAAAAA,AAAAAA" every 6 seconds.
I use these statements to treat the string:

```
            stringOut=stringOut.Replace("-",",");
            string[] valor_1=stringOut.Split(',');
            int i_C_AR=Convert.ToInt32(lbl_contador.Text);

            mx_02=Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[1])-Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[2]);
            mx_07=Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[2])-Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[3]);
            mx_10=Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[3]);
```

In most cases, we get the string without problems.

Sometimes the App aborts because of some character in the wrong place after these statements.

```
mx_02=Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[1])-Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[2]);
mx_07=Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[2])-Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[3]);
mx_10=Convert.ToInt32(valor_1[3]);
```

How to protect the App to no break?

Comment: What does it say when it 'aborts'?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 can only accept numerical strings.Its bound to fail if a non numeric string is passed.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should work out *why* you're getting bad data. Is this really expected, or does it represent a bug elsewhere in your system, which possibly *should* lead to the app terminating instead of continuing with bad data?

You can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead of `Convert.ToInt32`. This will allow you to detect errors without having to catch exceptions (which is an alternative).

`TryParse` returns a `bool` result saying whether parsing was successful or not, and uses an `out` parameter to store the result. You'll need to introduce extra local variables to store the parse results, before performing arithmetic later. For example, you may want something like:

```
// Rename these to be meaningful - in general your variable names should be
// clearer, and ideally without the underscores
int first, second, third;
if (!int.TryParse(valor_1[1], out first) ||
    !int.TryParse(valor_1[2], out second) ||
    !int.TryParse(valor_1[3], out third))
{
    // Do whatever you need to with invalid input
}
else
{
    mx_02 = first - second;
    mx_07 = second - third;
    mx_10 = third;
}
```

Note that this also reduces the number of parsing operations you'll be performing.

Comment: Using the code above not leaving this error anymore.
How to concatenate the contents of variable in the label name?

Comment: @user1635148: Sorry, it's not clear what you mean - but `string.Format` is probably what you're after.

Comment: How to concatenate the contents of a variable in the name of an object as a label?
The valor_1[0] received from 01 to 06, always this way. According to the numbers, the system filled out a label. Sample: lbl_01_temp, lbl_02_temp, lbl_03_temp, lbl_04_temp, lbl_05_temp, lbl_06_temp.

Comment: @user1635148: That hasn't really clarified anything. Objects don't have names, in general. It sounds like you're really asking a different question now - so instead of talking in comments, create a new (and clear) question. EDIT: Since your comment edit - don't do that. If you have a collection of variables, put them in a collection (e.g. an array or a list). You shouldn't be trying to access variables dynamically by name.

Comment: This is valid?
    if(!int.TryParse(valor_1[1],out i_1o)||
      !int.TryParse(valor_1[2],out i_2o)||
      !int.TryParse(valor_1[3],out i_3o))
      {
      mx_02=Convert.ToInt32("L_HM_"+String.Format(s_ID)+"_02mm");
      mx_07=Convert.ToInt32("L_HM_"+String.Format(s_ID)+"_07mm");
      mx_10=Convert.ToInt32("L_HM_"+String.Format(s_ID)+"_10mm");
      }

Comment: @user1635148: It's still not clear what you're trying to do, and it sounds like you should *really* be asking this in a different question. I've answered your question about how to avoid parsing exceptions - this is a question about how to format. (And no, that's not a good way of doing it - you should use a single call to `string.Format`.)

Comment: Thank you.
I be asking a new question. Best Regrads, ocaccy

Answer (score 0):

You can use int.TryParse, or catch the exception, which will be simpler

```
try{
// place faulty code here
}catch(Exception ex)
{
// handle exception if you care
}
```

Comment: Throwing a try/catch on something you can solve with a TryParse is like ordering a whole meal while you only need a sandwich: a waste of resources. It's definitely an anti-pattern.

Comment: His code gets that message once in 6 seconds, and exception occurs seldom. My choice is with less code. If there was only one integer to parse - you are sure right.

Comment: It's not only about performance. You also mask any other unforeseen error that might occur. If I see constructions like this in codebases I work on, I get rid of them.

Comment: I have a sample:
The valor_1[] has 6 fields.
[0]="・06" [1]="03699" [2]="01565" [3]="||675" 
At the moment I'm doing tests with TryParse, tomorrow I will test the try catch.